# How to use tooltip on bootstrip with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Hi i'm using bootstrap with angularjs to my project. I searched and tried some methods for show some text in tooltip. But its not working. Code is here... please help me out

<div popover-placement="up" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover=" Help contents displays here"> Help? </div>

<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="Help contents displays here tooltip"> Help? </div>

These two methods also not working... How to fix it?

Comment: Your question looks kind of weird, but have a look at the Angular UI Bootstrap project: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. Use this for replacing bootstraps javascript by angular directives.

Comment: I want to do with normal angular js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use can use uiJqConfig for details

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

just need to add this module

```
myapp.value('uiJqConfig', {
// The Tooltip namespace
tooltip: {
    // Tooltip options. This object will be used as the defaults
    placement: 'right'
 }
```

});

and u can use it in your html like this

```
<span title="this is my text" ui-jq="tooltip">

 you can also change the position like

<span title="this is my text" ui-jq="tooltip"  tooltip-placement="left">
```

Comment: Is not possible to do with normal angularjs?

Comment: For this you need to add ui bootstrap

Comment: If i add ui bootstrap, whether it will affect my normal bootstrap styles?